# What routing setting do to ping other machines on other subnets through VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, ping, subnet

To help explain my problem, I drew a diagram:

[net draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C24YL.png)

What I've managed to do so far is: I can ping the 192.168.200.101 machine from the 192.168.100.200/192.168.50.1 machine. To do this, I run the command on the 192.168.100.200/192.168.50.1 machine:

```
route add -net 192.168.200.0/24 gw 192.168.50.1
```

That actually seemed pretty strange to me, because I actually thought that as long as I didn't execute this command on 192.168.50.2/192.168.100.100

```
route add -net 192.168.50.0/24 gw 192.168.200.101
```

the ping described above shouldn't work. Why is that still working?

But what I can't definitely do is when I try to ping the 192.168.200.100 or 192.168.200.1 machine from the 192.168.100.200/192.168.50.1 machine. I've tried different commands but still fail, can anyone help me which command I have to execute in the routing table on 192.168.50.2/192.168.100.100/192.168.200.101 to get this working?

Comment: What does Wireshark or tcpdump show about where the ping packets go?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have so many subnets in such a small network.
Your routers might perhaps be better configured as
bridge/access-path rather than as DHCP servers.

Anyway, to make everything into one big network doesn't require routes.
All you need to do is define all subnets with a netmask of `255.255.0.0`.
This will convert everything into just one `192.168.x.x` network.